# Qt c++ Issue receiving data weighing scale Ohaus aviator 7000

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to establisch a serial port connection to my Aviator 7000 weighing scale using Qt c++. The expected result would be a succesfull communication through the use of a byte command.
Sadly I don't receive any bytes back from the scale. below you can find what I tried so far:

```
    const int Max_attempts = 5;
    const int Max_sleep = 125;

    int attemps;
    attemps = 0;
    while (true)
    {

        int enq {5};
        QByteArray bytes;
        bytes.setNum(enq);
        m_serial->write(bytes);

        m_serial->waitForReadyRead(Max_sleep);

        if (m_serial->bytesAvailable() !=0)
        {
            qDebug() << m_serial->bytesAvailable() ;
            qDebug() << "connected" << m_serial->readAll();
            break;
        }

        attemps += 1;

        if (attemps == Max_attempts)
        {
            qDebug() << "no connection established";
            break;
        }
    }
```

Kind regards,
Tibo

Comment: Have you tried to use a serial client like TeraTerm and checked that the serial port actually works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this manual](https://1l8w3d121kgy2lr9f827bgqfvba-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Aviator_service-manual.pdf) you are supposed to send a byte `0x05` but you are sending `0x35` (the character "5").

Use

```
bytes.append('\X05');
```

Comment: Yes that fixed it thank you